# scrolling not working after adding bootstrap in ie mobile version browser

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, windows-phone-8, ie-mobile

I have made a responsive site for mobile & tab devices. I attached Bootstrap styles in it which is working fine for all mobiles & tabs but it is not scrolling in IE mobile version browser. In Android browsers, it all works fine. What would be the problem in this?

[This is my site](http://brightcm.com/App/School.aspx)

Code

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head><meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" /><meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, minimum-scale=1, maximum-scale=1" /><link href="css/bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" /><title>
    Home
</title>

<style>
@font-face{font-family:KINKEE; src: url(http://brightcm.com/font/KINKEE.TTF)}

body{background:#000}
.main_container{
    width:100%;
    height:100%;
    background:url(img/bg.png) no-repeat;
    background-size:cover;
    font-family:"Century Gothic";
    overflow:auto;
    position:absolute;
    top:0;
    left:0;
    bottom:0;
}
.header{width:100%; height:120px; background:#a6e0fa; position:fixed; z-index:500}
.select {
   background: url(img/new_arrow.png) no-repeat right #fff;
   color:#000;
   width: 120px;
   padding: 5px;
   font-size: 16px;
   line-height: 1;
   border: 1px solid #333;
   border-radius:0;
   height: 34px;
   -webkit-appearance:none;
   -moz-appearance:none;
   outline:none;
    }

ul.list_view li{margin:0 0 0 -35px; display:block; height:auto}

.search_box{width:100%; background:#fff; border:1px solid #ffcc00;  border-radius:5px; height:50px; float:left; margin:0 10px 0 0}
input.text_box{width:80%; padding:7px 0 7px 0; border:none; outline:none; margin:9px 0 0 5px; float:left; moz-outline:none; -webkit-outline:none}

.main_page{top:130px; width:99%; position:absolute; height:auto;}

</style>

<style type="text/css">
.modalPopup
{
background-color: #696969;
filter: alpha(opacity=40);
opacity: 0.7;
xindex:-1;
}
</style>

</head>
<body>
    <form method="post" action="School.aspx" id="form1">

<script type="text/javascript">
//<![CDATA[
var theForm = document.forms['form1'];
if (!theForm) {
    theForm = document.form1;
}
function __doPostBack(eventTarget, eventArgument) {
    if (!theForm.onsubmit || (theForm.onsubmit() != false)) {
        theForm.__EVENTTARGET.value = eventTarget;
        theForm.__EVENTARGUMENT.value = eventArgument;
        theForm.submit();
    }
}
//]]>
</script>


<div class="aspNetHidden">

</div>
    <div>

    <div class="main_container">
    <div class="header">
        <div style="padding:5px 8px 5px 8px; float:left; width:100%;">
        <div style="float:left; width:50%; color:#06F; font-size:1.5em; font-family:KINKEE;">
           Padhai Guru
        </div>

        <div style="width:50%; float:right;">
        <select name="DropDown_District" onchange="javascript:setTimeout(&#39;__doPostBack(\&#39;DropDown_District\&#39;,\&#39;\&#39;)&#39;, 0)" id="DropDown_District" class="select" style="float:right">
    <option value="Bangalore">Bangalore</option>
    <option value="Chennai">Chennai</option>
    <option value="Delhi">Delhi</option>
    <option value="Kolkata">Kolkata</option>
    <option selected="selected" value="Mumbai">Mumbai</option>
    <option value="Pune">Pune</option>

</select>
        </div>

         </div>

         <div style="padding:5px 8px 5px 8px; float:left; width:100%">
            <div class="search_box">
                <input class="text_box" type="text" placeholder="e.g. schools, colleges" />
                <input type="button" style="width:50px; height:50px; background-color:transparent; border:none; background:url(img/search_icon.png) center no-repeat; cursor:pointer; outline:none; float:right"  />

            </div>
         </div>
    </div><!--header Ends-->


   <!--Main Page Start--> <div class="main_page">
                            <div style="text-align:center; width:95%; color:#000; font-size:12px; font-weight:bold;">Schools In Mumbai</div>

                            <div style="width:95%; margin:0 auto;">
                                <div style="50%; float:left">
                                    <span>Area</span><br />                                      
                                        <select name="DropDownArea" onchange="javascript:setTimeout(&#39;__doPostBack(\&#39;DropDownArea\&#39;,\&#39;\&#39;)&#39;, 0)" id="DropDownArea" class="select" style="background:#fff url(img/new_arrow2.png) no-repeat right; -webkit-appearance:none; color:#000; border-radius:5px;-webkit-border-radius:5px;-moz-border-radius:5px;">
    <option selected="selected" value="All">All</option>
    <option value="Andheri East">Andheri East</option>
    <option value="Andheri West">Andheri West</option>
    <option value="Bandra East">Bandra East</option>
    <option value="Bandra West">Bandra West</option>
    <option value="Bandra Kurla Complex">Bandra Kurla Complex</option>
    <option value="Bhayandar East">Bhayandar East</option>
    <option value="Bhayandar West">Bhayandar West</option>
    <option value="Borivali East">Borivali East</option>
    <option value="Borivali West">Borivali West</option>
    <option value="Chembur">Chembur</option>
    <option value="Colaba">Colaba</option>
    <option value="Dadar">Dadar</option>
    <option value="Dahisar East">Dahisar East</option>
    <option value="Dahisar West">Dahisar West</option>
    <option value="Grant Road">Grant Road</option>
    <option value="Goregaon East">Goregaon East</option>
    <option value="Goregaon West">Goregaon West</option>
    <option value="Jogeshwari East">Jogeshwari East</option>
    <option value="Jogeshwari West">Jogeshwari West</option>
    <option value="Juhu">Juhu</option>
    <option value="Kandivali East">Kandivali East</option>
    <option value="Kandivali West">Kandivali West</option>
    <option value="Khar East">Khar East</option>
    <option value="Khar West">Khar West</option>
    <option value="Mahim Junction">Mahim Junction</option>
    <option value="Malad East">Malad East</option>
    <option value="Malad West">Malad West</option>
    <option value="Matunga">Matunga</option>
    <option value="Mira Road East">Mira Road East</option>
    <option value="Mira Road West">Mira Road West</option>
    <option value="Mumbai Central">Mumbai Central</option>
    <option value="Powai">Powai</option>
    <option value="Santacruz east">Santacruz east</option>
    <option value="Santacruz West">Santacruz West</option>
    <option value="Sion">Sion</option>
    <option value="Vasai East">Vasai East</option>
    <option value="Vasai West">Vasai West</option>
    <option value="Vile Parle East">Vile Parle East</option>
    <option value="Vile Parle West">Vile Parle West</option>
    <option value="Virar East">Virar East</option>
    <option value="Virar West">Virar West</option>

</select>
                                </div>

                                <div style="50%; float:right">
                                    <span>Board</span><br />
                                        <select name="DDBoard" onchange="javascript:setTimeout(&#39;__doPostBack(\&#39;DDBoard\&#39;,\&#39;\&#39;)&#39;, 0)" id="DDBoard" class="select" style="background:#fff url(img/new_arrow2.png) no-repeat right; -webkit-appearance:none; color:#000; border-radius:5px;-webkit-border-radius:5px;-moz-border-radius:5px;">
    <option selected="selected" value="All">All</option>
    <option value="CBSE">CBSE</option>
    <option value="IB">IB</option>
    <option value="ICSE">ICSE</option>
    <option value="IGCSE">IGCSE</option>
    <option value="SSC">SSC</option>

</select>
                                </div>                                                           
                            </div>

                            <div style="width:95%; margin:65px auto; background:url(img/tansparency.png) repeat; padding:3px; height:100%; position:relative; display:table">


            <ul id="ListViewSchool_itemPlaceholderContainer" style="" class="list_view">

             <li style="list-style:none">

           <div style="width:80%; float:right; margin:15px 0;"> <span style="font-weight:bold"> <span id="ListViewSchool_Sch_Name_0">Fidai Girls Educational Institute</span> </span>
           <div style="margin-top:5px; font-size:12px"> <span id="ListViewSchool_Sch_Address_0">Fidai Baugh, Opposite Laram Centre, S V Road, Andheri West, Mumbai - 400058 </span> </div> <div style="font-size:12px; margin-top:6px"> <span id="ListViewSchool_Sch_Contact_0">26284692</span> </div></div>
           <div style="width:15%; float:left"><img src="img/1.png" width="35" height="35" style="margin-top:10px" /></div>

            </li>



           <li style="list-style:none" >

           <div style="width:80%; float:right; margin:15px 0;"> <span style="font-weight:bold"> <span id="ListViewSchool_Sch_Name_1">LORETO CONVENT SCHOOL</span> </span>
           <div style="margin-top:5px; font-size:12px"> <span id="ListViewSchool_Sch_Address_1">RCF Township, Chembur,Mumbai - 400 074</span> </div>  <div style="font-size:12px; margin-top:6px"> <span id="ListViewSchool_Sch_Contact_1">25536680</span> </div></div>
           <div style="width:15%; float:left"><img src="img/1.png" width="35" height="35" style="margin-top:10px" /></div>
           </li>



             <li style="list-style:none">

           <div style="width:80%; float:right; margin:15px 0;"> <span style="font-weight:bold"> <span id="ListViewSchool_Sch_Name_2">The Convent of Jesus and Mary</span> </span>
           <div style="margin-top:5px; font-size:12px"> <span id="ListViewSchool_Sch_Address_2">Convent of Jesus and Mary, 15 Nathalal Parekh Marg, Mumbai 400001</span> </div> <div style="font-size:12px; margin-top:6px"> <span id="ListViewSchool_Sch_Contact_2">22020474</span> </div></div>
           <div style="width:15%; float:left"><img src="img/1.png" width="35" height="35" style="margin-top:10px" /></div>

            </li>



           <li style="list-style:none" >

           <div style="width:80%; float:right; margin:15px 0;"> <span style="font-weight:bold"> <span id="ListViewSchool_Sch_Name_3">Mount Mary Convent High School</span> </span>
           <div style="margin-top:5px; font-size:12px"> <span id="ListViewSchool_Sch_Address_3">60, Mount Mary Hill roa Bandra West</span> </div>  <div style="font-size:12px; margin-top:6px"> <span id="ListViewSchool_Sch_Contact_3">0</span> </div></div>
           <div style="width:15%; float:left"><img src="img/1.png" width="35" height="35" style="margin-top:10px" /></div>
           </li>



             <li style="list-style:none">

           <div style="width:80%; float:right; margin:15px 0;"> <span style="font-weight:bold"> <span id="ListViewSchool_Sch_Name_4">Smt Kamala Mehta School for Blind</span> </span>
           <div style="margin-top:5px; font-size:12px"> <span id="ListViewSchool_Sch_Address_4">Dada Saheb Phalke Marg, Parel Mumbai, MH 400014</span> </div> <div style="font-size:12px; margin-top:6px"> <span id="ListViewSchool_Sch_Contact_4">0</span> </div></div>
           <div style="width:15%; float:left"><img src="img/1.png" width="35" height="35" style="margin-top:10px" /></div>

            </li>



           <li style="list-style:none" >

           <div style="width:80%; float:right; margin:15px 0;"> <span style="font-weight:bold"> <span id="ListViewSchool_Sch_Name_5">Blind Pupples Welfare Association</span> </span>
           <div style="margin-top:5px; font-size:12px"> <span id="ListViewSchool_Sch_Address_5">Alfate Apartment, Coororation Bank Near Miraroad Station, Mira Road, Thane - 401107</span> </div>  <div style="font-size:12px; margin-top:6px"> <span id="ListViewSchool_Sch_Contact_5">9322182674</span> </div></div>
           <div style="width:15%; float:left"><img src="img/1.png" width="35" height="35" style="margin-top:10px" /></div>
           </li>



             <li style="list-style:none">

           <div style="width:80%; float:right; margin:15px 0;"> <span style="font-weight:bold"> <span id="ListViewSchool_Sch_Name_6">National Fedration Of Blind</span> </span>
           <div style="margin-top:5px; font-size:12px"> <span id="ListViewSchool_Sch_Address_6">485/2/A/3 Prapti Cooperative Housing Society Ltd, Chiku Wadi, Borivali West, Mumbai - 400092</span> </div> <div style="font-size:12px; margin-top:6px"> <span id="ListViewSchool_Sch_Contact_6">9967312981</span> </div></div>
           <div style="width:15%; float:left"><img src="img/1.png" width="35" height="35" style="margin-top:10px" /></div>

            </li>



           <li style="list-style:none" >

           <div style="width:80%; float:right; margin:15px 0;"> <span style="font-weight:bold"> <span id="ListViewSchool_Sch_Name_7">Smt Kamla Mehta School For The Blind</span> </span>
           <div style="margin-top:5px; font-size:12px"> <span id="ListViewSchool_Sch_Address_7">Off Hindmata Cinema, 160 Dadasaheb Phalke Road, Dadar East, Mumbai - 400014</span> </div>  <div style="font-size:12px; margin-top:6px"> <span id="ListViewSchool_Sch_Contact_7">24183144</span> </div></div>
           <div style="width:15%; float:left"><img src="img/1.png" width="35" height="35" style="margin-top:10px" /></div>
           </li>



             <li style="list-style:none">

           <div style="width:80%; float:right; margin:15px 0;"> <span style="font-weight:bold"> <span id="ListViewSchool_Sch_Name_8">Royal Girls High School</span> </span>
           <div style="margin-top:5px; font-size:12px"> <span id="ListViewSchool_Sch_Address_8">Royal College Campus, Penkarpada, Mira Road, Thane - 401107</span> </div> <div style="font-size:12px; margin-top:6px"> <span id="ListViewSchool_Sch_Contact_8">28454660</span> </div></div>
           <div style="width:15%; float:left"><img src="img/1.png" width="35" height="35" style="margin-top:10px" /></div>

            </li>



           <li style="list-style:none" >

           <div style="width:80%; float:right; margin:15px 0;"> <span style="font-weight:bold"> <span id="ListViewSchool_Sch_Name_9">Mary Immaculate Girls High School</span> </span>
           <div style="margin-top:5px; font-size:12px"> <span id="ListViewSchool_Sch_Address_9">Damodar Hall Compound, Near St Francis Bus Stop, Mandapeshwar Road, Borivali West, Mumbai - 400103</span> </div>  <div style="font-size:12px; margin-top:6px"> <span id="ListViewSchool_Sch_Contact_9">28931311</span> </div></div>
           <div style="width:15%; float:left"><img src="img/1.png" width="35" height="35" style="margin-top:10px" /></div>
           </li>



             <li style="list-style:none">

           <div style="width:80%; float:right; margin:15px 0;"> <span style="font-weight:bold"> <span id="ListViewSchool_Sch_Name_10">St Annes High School</span> </span>
           <div style="margin-top:5px; font-size:12px"> <span id="ListViewSchool_Sch_Address_10">Near Veer Savarkar Garden, Lokmanya Tilak Road, Borivali West, Mumbai - 400091</span> </div> <div style="font-size:12px; margin-top:6px"> <span id="ListViewSchool_Sch_Contact_10">28992033</span> </div></div>
           <div style="width:15%; float:left"><img src="img/1.png" width="35" height="35" style="margin-top:10px" /></div>

            </li>



           <li style="list-style:none" >

           <div style="width:80%; float:right; margin:15px 0;"> <span style="font-weight:bold"> <span id="ListViewSchool_Sch_Name_11">Carmel Of St Joseph School</span> </span>
           <div style="margin-top:5px; font-size:12px"> <span id="ListViewSchool_Sch_Address_11">Orlem, Marve Road, Malad West, Mumbai - 400064</span> </div>  <div style="font-size:12px; margin-top:6px"> <span id="ListViewSchool_Sch_Contact_11">28650144</span> </div></div>
           <div style="width:15%; float:left"><img src="img/1.png" width="35" height="35" style="margin-top:10px" /></div>
           </li>



             <li style="list-style:none">

           <div style="width:80%; float:right; margin:15px 0;"> <span style="font-weight:bold"> <span id="ListViewSchool_Sch_Name_12">St Marys Convent High School</span> </span>
           <div style="margin-top:5px; font-size:12px"> <span id="ListViewSchool_Sch_Address_12">Nahur Road, Mulund West, Mumbai - 400080</span> </div> <div style="font-size:12px; margin-top:6px"> <span id="ListViewSchool_Sch_Contact_12">25680920</span> </div></div>
           <div style="width:15%; float:left"><img src="img/1.png" width="35" height="35" style="margin-top:10px" /></div>

            </li>



           <li style="list-style:none" >

           <div style="width:80%; float:right; margin:15px 0;"> <span style="font-weight:bold"> <span id="ListViewSchool_Sch_Name_13">Posat Foundation</span> </span>
           <div style="margin-top:5px; font-size:12px"> <span id="ListViewSchool_Sch_Address_13">A/2 Highrise Apt, Opp Mary Emmaculate Girls High School, Laxman Matre Rd, Borivali West, Mumbai - 400103</span> </div>  <div style="font-size:12px; margin-top:6px"> <span id="ListViewSchool_Sch_Contact_13">28956933</span> </div></div>
           <div style="width:15%; float:left"><img src="img/1.png" width="35" height="35" style="margin-top:10px" /></div>
           </li>



             <li style="list-style:none">

           <div style="width:80%; float:right; margin:15px 0;"> <span style="font-weight:bold"> <span id="ListViewSchool_Sch_Name_14">Missionaries Of Charity</span> </span>
           <div style="margin-top:5px; font-size:12px"> <span id="ListViewSchool_Sch_Address_14">Shantidaan, Gorai Creek, Near Gorai Bus Depot, L T Road, Borivali West, Mumbai - 400091</span> </div> <div style="font-size:12px; margin-top:6px"> <span id="ListViewSchool_Sch_Contact_14">28671362</span> </div></div>
           <div style="width:15%; float:left"><img src="img/1.png" width="35" height="35" style="margin-top:10px" /></div>

            </li>



           <li style="list-style:none" >

           <div style="width:80%; float:right; margin:15px 0;"> <span style="font-weight:bold"> <span id="ListViewSchool_Sch_Name_15">Wonderland Special School     </span> </span>
           <div style="margin-top:5px; font-size:12px"> <span id="ListViewSchool_Sch_Address_15">8 A, 103, Alica Nagar, Lokhandwala Construction, Akurli Road, Kandivali East, Mumbai - 400101</span> </div>  <div style="font-size:12px; margin-top:6px"> <span id="ListViewSchool_Sch_Contact_15">9820409686</span> </div></div>
           <div style="width:15%; float:left"><img src="img/1.png" width="35" height="35" style="margin-top:10px" /></div>
           </li>



             <li style="list-style:none">

           <div style="width:80%; float:right; margin:15px 0;"> <span style="font-weight:bold"> <span id="ListViewSchool_Sch_Name_16">Vallabhdas Dagra Indian Society For Mentally Retarded</span> </span>
           <div style="margin-top:5px; font-size:12px"> <span id="ListViewSchool_Sch_Address_16">V D Indian Society For Mentally Retarded, Station Road, Malad West, Mumbai 400064</span> </div> <div style="font-size:12px; margin-top:6px"> <span id="ListViewSchool_Sch_Contact_16">28810581</span> </div></div>
           <div style="width:15%; float:left"><img src="img/1.png" width="35" height="35" style="margin-top:10px" /></div>

            </li>



           <li style="list-style:none" >

           <div style="width:80%; float:right; margin:15px 0;"> <span style="font-weight:bold"> <span id="ListViewSchool_Sch_Name_17">Vrajlal Parekh Vidyanidhi High School</span> </span>
           <div style="margin-top:5px; font-size:12px"> <span id="ListViewSchool_Sch_Address_17">Juhu Scheme, Vidyanidhi Marg, Juhu, Mumbai - 400049</span> </div>  <div style="font-size:12px; margin-top:6px"> <span id="ListViewSchool_Sch_Contact_17">26255634</span> </div></div>
           <div style="width:15%; float:left"><img src="img/1.png" width="35" height="35" style="margin-top:10px" /></div>
           </li>



             <li style="list-style:none">

           <div style="width:80%; float:right; margin:15px 0;"> <span style="font-weight:bold"> <span id="ListViewSchool_Sch_Name_18">The Bombay International School</span> </span>
           <div style="margin-top:5px; font-size:12px"> <span id="ListViewSchool_Sch_Address_18">Gilbert Building, Babulnath 2nd Cross Road, Mumbai 400007.</span> </div> <div style="font-size:12px; margin-top:6px"> <span id="ListViewSchool_Sch_Contact_18">23648206</span> </div></div>
           <div style="width:15%; float:left"><img src="img/1.png" width="35" height="35" style="margin-top:10px" /></div>

            </li>



           <li style="list-style:none" >

           <div style="width:80%; float:right; margin:15px 0;"> <span style="font-weight:bold"> <span id="ListViewSchool_Sch_Name_19">Army School</span> </span>
           <div style="margin-top:5px; font-size:12px"> <span id="ListViewSchool_Sch_Address_19">Opp Ashwini Hospital, Dr. Moose Rd. Colaba.</span> </div>  <div style="font-size:12px; margin-top:6px"> <span id="ListViewSchool_Sch_Contact_19">22182547</span> </div></div>
           <div style="width:15%; float:left"><img src="img/1.png" width="35" height="35" style="margin-top:10px" /></div>
           </li>

            </ul>
            <div style="padding-bottom:10px">
                <span id="ListViewSchool_DataPager1"></span>
            </div>


                            </div>                      
                           </div>


    </div>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Post your codes here.

Comment: You said ie mobile version browser, do you mean Windows Phone 7 / 8's browsers? Which browser & device are you working on?

Comment: It's windows phone-8 browser

Comment: Several problems in your CSS, but *not* related to scrolling: 1. never use `font-family` with 1 font; 2. some effects are not made cross-browser (`border-radius`, `filter`, etc); 3. use `em` instead of `px` in font size in mobile browsers; 4. `xindex` ?! 5. `Century Gothic` is not a valid web font; 6. where is the `DOCTYPE`? 7. `onchange` syntax issues... etc.